# how to drill anti-rotation holes in enclosures?

Tags: wiring, enclosure

I am wondering how those holes with a flat for connectors are opened in enclosures. I'd like to know how do to it when prototyping world and in production for aluminum and in plastic.

Comment: Hm, do you have a picture of such a hole? Even though you've accepted an answer, it's not clear to me what you actually mean.

Comment: If  you are trying to make a round hole with a notch, you can drill the hole and use a file to make the notch.

Comment: For prototyping, you can laser-cut things. Or just drill a hole without a flat and screw the connector in tightly, accepting that it's going to come loose after a while.

Comment: I believe our machinist sometimes uses an NC machine to route these and other complex holes for panel-mount connectors. A small enough bit does a pretty decent job. This is a reasonable solution if your volumes aren't high.

Comment: @pipe http://www.vadcon.com/info/holesize.html here are some examples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't drill such holes. Instead, you get a punch. For instance, if you're trying to install BNC connectors you need a 1/2" D punch, such as [this](https://www.grainger.com/product/GREENLEE-Punch-4JA58?s_pp=false&picUrl=//static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/4JA59_AS01?$smthumb$)...

[image: Punch and Die]

And yes, they are expensive. Prototyping will use this sort of punch, which is hand-powered. For production you get a punch/die set for a press.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll have to find a cheaper way I think...

Comment: @nraynaud, you can cut them out with a mill too.  (Though it can be tricky to hold a big panel down.)  I've used drills and hand files, dremel grinder, nibbler... for the nibbler google "Adel hand nibbler"

Comment: Laser cutting can do it too. And will be cheaper for prototypes.